# Point alway replace first time open file in vs-code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I open the first file the point so weird:

[image]

It replaces my text I don't want this I want to insert in the position of my point

[image]

Comment: I think with a block cursor it is hard to tell whether you have accidentally selected the letter rather than set a cursor before it - perhaps you are selecting.  Switch to a line cursor and see if you still get replacements.

Comment: So weird I disabled some extension and it has gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these issues, I remove some extension, and It disappear